# What is Meteor.settings.S3Directory

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to install [cropuploader](https://github.com/jamgold/cropuploader) with meteor-slingshot. The setup documents refer to `Meteor.settings.S3Directory` but I have no idea what it's referring to because I thought S3 worked on buckets. If someone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

S3Directory refers to a directory inside the bucket.  Think of it as a top-level folder in the bucket. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/jamgold/cropuploader/blob/master/cropuploader-common.js), it is optional.

Comment: So to use cropuploader would I delete Meteor.settings.S3Directory

Comment: You could just pass an empty string in instead of Meteor.settings.S3Directory.

Comment: Sorry, how do I pass an empty string?

Comment: `CropUploader.init(MySlingShotDirectiveName, "");`